# Regular expression jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having some problems using reg expression to remove unwanted spaces in my title. This is my code:

```
<ul>
 <li>
    <a href="#make/281">
      <img src="/images/cook-hat.svg">
      <span class="label label-primary">label</span>
      <div class="title-box"><span class="title">      my title     </span></div>
      <span class="goal-list">4</span>
    </a>
 </li>


$("li").val(
  $("span.title").text().replace(/\n/g, "")
  .replace(/\s/g,'')
);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Only test of the `<span class="title">` should be replaced or entire `li` element ?

Comment: I believe `li has no valu` why use `.val()` ? use `.text()` or `.html()` according to need

Comment: it is working why is the problem?

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/zzpppud8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Try this:

```js
$("li").text(
  $("span.title").text().replace(/\n/g, "")
  .replace(/\s/g, ' ')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#make/281">
      <img src="/images/cook-hat.svg">
      <span class="label label-primary">label</span>
      <div class="title-box"><span class="title">      my title     </span>
      </div>
      <span class="goal-list">4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** To set text of multiple `li` elements.

```js
$("li").text(
  function() {
    return $(this).find("span.title").text().replace(/\n/g, "")
      .replace(/\s/g, ' ')
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#make/281">
      <img src="/images/cook-hat.svg">
      <span class="label label-primary">label</span>
      <div class="title-box"><span class="title">      my title     </span>
      </div>
      <span class="goal-list">4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#make/281">
      <img src="/images/cook-hat.svg">
      <span class="label label-primary">label</span>
      <div class="title-box"><span class="title">      my title     </span>
      </div>
      <span class="goal-list">4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works good what if I want to go through a list of multiple li? should I use a loop for that?

Comment: Is this correct?

$("li").each(function(){
   $("span.title").text().replace(/\n/g, "")
   .replace(/\s/g, ' ')
});

Answer (score 1):

> .replace(/\s/g,'')

will replace all spaces in the text. Not sure you want that since you said `remove unwanted spaces`.

If you want to trim the string from following and trailing spaces, then simply do

```
$("li").html(  $("span.title").text().trim() );
```

Comment: `/g` match all occurrences

Comment: @RayonDabre you are right, it won't. Updated the code